# Summing arrays correctly

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I'm using MASM & Irvine 32bit Assembly, and I have arrays A, B, C, and I'm stacked on performing A + B = C, summing each [i] item of array A with array B and writing to array C.

For instance,

```
 arrA 1, 2, 4, 1
 +
 arrB 2, 1, 1, 3 
 =
 arrC 3, 3, 5, 4
```

I've tried to work with pointers, but I had 00, 00, 00, 0F output.

Don't pay attention to StrHex_MY procedure, it is tested on outputting arrays.

Code:

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

include \Irvine\Irvine32.inc
includelib \Irvine\kernel32.lib
includelib \Irvine\user32.lib
include module.inc

.data
  CaptionGreet BYTE "Test me", 0

  arrA DWORD 1, 2, 4, 1 
  arrB DWORD 2, 1, 1, 3 
  arrC DWORD 0, 0, 0, 0

  toOut DB 64 dup(?)

.code

main PROC

    mov edi, OFFSET arrA ; Address of arrA
    mov esi, OFFSET arrB ; Address of arrB

    mov eax, 0 ; Register with result

    mov ecx, LENGTHOF arrA ; Lenght of arrays

    L1:
        add eax, [edi] ; Add current arrA element to eax
        add eax, [esi] ; Add current arrB element to eax

        add edi, TYPE arrA ; Move pointer to the next arrA element
        add esi, TYPE arrB ; Move pointer to the next arrB element

        mov arrC, eax ; Move current eax value to arrC

        loop L1

    ; Converting result to HEX toOut. Don't pay attention to this part
    ; ----
    push OFFSET toOut
    push OFFSET arrC
    push 256
    call StrHex_MY
    ; ---

    ; Output result
    INVOKE MessageBoxA, 0, ADDR toOut, ADDR CaptionGreet, 0
    INVOKE ExitProcess,0

main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: So it outputs 0F because it sums all elements of those two arrays, and now I'm stack on accessing each arrC element and rewriting it with sum of arrA + arrB current elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to add each item of `arrA` to its correspondent item of `arrB` and to store it to the correspondent item of `arrC`. So

```
add eax, [edi] ; Add current arrA element to eax
```

is wrong. You have to "reinitialise" `EAX` with the item:

```
mov eax, [edi] ; Copy current arrA element to eax
```

You need a third pointer to arrC. Right now you store the result repeatedly to the first item of arrC. I've chosen `EBX` as third pointer.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
  CaptionGreet BYTE "Test me", 0

  arrA DWORD 1, 2, 4, 1
  arrB DWORD 2, 1, 1, 3
  arrC DWORD 0, 0, 0, 0

  toOut DB 64 dup(?)

.code

main PROC

    mov edi, OFFSET arrA    ; Address of arrA
    mov esi, OFFSET arrB    ; Address of arrB
    mov ebx, Offset arrC    ; Address of arrC

    mov eax, 0              ; Register with result

    mov ecx, LENGTHOF arrA  ; Length of arrays

    L1:
        mov eax, [edi]      ; Copy current arrA element to eax
        add eax, [esi]      ; Add current arrB element to eax

        add edi, TYPE arrA  ; Move pointer to the next arrA element
        add esi, TYPE arrB  ; Move pointer to the next arrB element

        mov [ebx], eax      ; Move current eax value to current arrC element
        add ebx, TYPE arrC  ; Move pointer to the next arrC element

        loop L1

    mov esi, OFFSET arrC
    mov ecx, 4
    mov ebx, 4
    call DumpMem


    INVOKE ExitProcess,0

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Thank you! 
 I wonder why it perfectly works even without 

`mov esi, OFFSET arrC , mov ecx, 4, mov ebx, 4` code. 

Could you please explain why do we need it there?

Comment: That block prepares the parameters for `DumpMem`, a function of Irvine's library to dump an array. Take a look at http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fdumpmem.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've also improved what @rkhb has answered, so now it performs not only adding arrA to corresponding arrB, but also it works with Carry flags. So if we want to perform a multiprecision addition operation, we need to present our numbers as an arrays and work with carry flags.

Didn't find a lot of information on it on the Internet, so if it is needed, here it is:

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

include \Irvine\Irvine32.inc
includelib \Irvine\kernel32.lib
includelib \Irvine\user32.lib
include module.inc

.data
  CaptionGreet BYTE "Last >> Last
  arrA DWORD 80010001h, 80020001h, 80030001h
  arrB DWORD 80000001h, 80000001h, 80000001h
  arrC DWORD 0, 0, 0

  toOut DB 64 dup(?)

.code

main PROC

    mov edi, OFFSET arrA    ; Address of arrA
    mov esi, OFFSET arrB    ; Address of arrB
    mov ebx, Offset arrC    ; Address of arrC

    mov eax, 0              ; Register with result
    pushad
    clc ; Make Carry flag zero

    mov ecx, LENGTHOF arrA  ; Length of arrays

    L1:
        pushfd ; Restore Carry flag
        mov eax, [edi]      ; Copy current arrA element to eax
        popfd
        adc eax, [esi]      ; Add current arrB element to eax, if Carry flag is non-zero, it is also added
        pushfd ; Push Carry flag to FLAGS register

        add edi, TYPE arrA  ; Move pointer to the next arrA element
        add esi, TYPE arrB  ; Move pointer to the next arrB element

        mov [ebx], eax      ; Move current eax value to current arrC element
        add ebx, TYPE arrC  ; Move pointer to the next arrC element
        popfd
        loop L1 

    ; Convert result to HEX toOut
    push OFFSET toOut
    push OFFSET arrC
    push 480
    call StrHex_MY

    ; Output result
    INVOKE MessageBoxA, 0, ADDR toOut, ADDR CaptionGreet, 0
    INVOKE ExitProcess,0

main ENDP
END main
```